# Mark all products of particular categories as draft Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I currently have 40,000 products in my woocommerce store which are published. Is there a way to mark all products of particular categories as a draft without manually changing them to draft via bulk edit, as I can only modify 200-300 before I get a timeout error. I dont want to delete any product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is to run a direct SQL query. The following will work

```
UPDATE wp_posts p 
JOIN wp_term_relationships r on p.id=r.object_id 
SET p.post_status='draft' 
WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id in (123, 456);
```

Replace 123, 456 with the relevant term ids.

Ensure to take a backup of the database before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks Anand. Its working fine. You have solved my problem.